# Specify a starting index for continuation of calculating Pi

Tags: c#, pi

This C# code will calculate Pi to whatever length I specify.  I want to be able to start at a given index without recalculating to that point.  Precision is not a great concern as this is a puzzle project but I do need this code to reproduce the same results over and over.  It works fine as is but I haven't been able to figure out how to modify for a starting point.

```
//Looking to pass BigInteger to specify a starting index for continuation of calculating Pi

    public static BigInteger GetPi(int digits, int iterations)
    {
        return 16 * ArcTan1OverX(5, digits).ElementAt(iterations)
            - 4 * ArcTan1OverX(239, digits).ElementAt(iterations);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<BigInteger> ArcTan1OverX(int x, int digits)
    {
        var mag = BigInteger.Pow(10, digits);
        var sum = BigInteger.Zero;
        bool sign = true;
        for (int i = 1; true; i += 2)
        {
            var cur = mag / (BigInteger.Pow(x, i) * i);
            if (sign)
            {
                sum += cur;
            }
            else
            {
                sum -= cur;
            }
            yield return sum;
            sign = !sign;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output?

Comment: GetPi(3,1) = 314

Comment: Or more specific:  GetPi(2,1,2) = 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [Machin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) with the Taylor serie expansion for Arctan. It should give you about 1.4 digits of precision for each "cycle" (see [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ealopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node12.html)). You can't "shortcut" the calculation of the Taylor serie. You can speed-up a little the program removing the `IEnumerable<BigInteger>` part and simply returning the nth iteration (the `yield` instruction has a cost) and by changing the `BigInteger.Pow` with a fixed multiplication. But the calculation will still be made iteratively. There is no known way for calculating PI with a precision of n digits in O(1) time.

Note that there are algorithms (see the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Rapidly_convergent_series)) that converge in a smaller number of cycles, but I'm not sure if they converge in a smaller number of operations (their cycles are much more complex).

An optimized version of the code:

```
public static BigInteger GetPi2(int digits, int iterations)
{
    return 16 * ArcTan1OverX2(5, digits, iterations)
        - 4 * ArcTan1OverX2(239, digits, iterations);
}

public static BigInteger ArcTan1OverX2(int x, int digits, int iterations)
{
    var mag = BigInteger.Pow(10, digits);
    var sum = BigInteger.Zero;
    bool sign = true;

    int imax = 1 + (2 * iterations);

    int xsquared = x * x;
    BigInteger pow = x;

    for (int i = 1; i <= imax; i += 2)
    {
        if (i != 1)
        {
            pow *= xsquared;
        }

        var cur = mag / (pow * i);

        if (sign)
        {
            sum += cur;
        }
        else
        {
            sum -= cur;
        }

        sign = !sign;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that being the case. I like your idea to drop the yield to increase performance.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarcSuther I'll even say that you can replace `BigInteger.Pow(x, i)` with an iterative `powPrev * xsquared` (where `xsquared` is precomputed). A single multiplication should be less expensive than a `Pow`. Written an example of the code.